# Octokit-js based app throws JSON web token error

Tags: node.js, github, octokit, github-app, octokit-js

I'm having issues with an octokit-based nodejs app that was working  just a couple of weeks ago. From nowhere, I'm getting auth errors that I've managed to debug to the point of getting this error message:

A JSON web token could not be decoded

This happens when I instanciate the Octokit for an installation App that works on Github and then ask anything of it (creating a PR, adding an issue, etc).

However, I'm not sure what does this mean. So far:

APP_ID and PRIVATE_KEY are variables stored in process.env.
The InstallationId I get from the Github app URL, and the other data (OWNER, REPO, etc) I've verified is correct.

This is a summarized version of my code:

```
const {Octokit} = require("@octokit/rest");
const { createAppAuth } = require("@octokit/auth-app");


const octokit = new Octokit({
  authStrategy: createAppAuth,
  auth: {
    appId: APP_ID,
    privateKey: PRIVATE_KEY,
    // optional: this will make appOctokit authenticate as app (JWT)
    //           or installation (access token), depending on the request URL
    installationId: process.env.INSTALLATION_ID,
  },
});

const test = async()=>
        await octokit.issues.create({
         owner: OWNER,
        repo: REPO,
        title: "Hello world from me",
        });


test()
```

What could be happening? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I just tested this code on a different machine and... it works. So, I'm baffled as to why it is not running in the original machine.

Comment: What changed between it working and not working? Did you update any libraries? If so, the first thing to check would be their respective issues list

Comment: Nothing. The app was ledt alone during the holidays, and it was working last time. I suspect something may have changed from github side, so I'm going through the dependabot notifications trying to establish what. However, there was one change we made to the machine: its clock wasn't sync, but I fixed that yesterday using a ntp server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The appId was wrong somehow. Quite embarrasing, but by testing on a new machine I just double checked all possible changes and found the issue.